# How disable scrollIntoView event when Colorbox use

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, colorbox

I have gallery from several elements like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="img/ZSAq4U5Ut98.jpg" class="container">…</a>
  <a href="img/rFbTrkdPOhA.jpg" class="container">…</a>
  <a href="img/bgqdOlCUKDY.jpg" class="container">…</a>
  <a href="img/3Ew4qOlZiMU.jpg" class="container">…</a>
  <a href="img/9KGN6V9U32c.jpg" class="container">…</a>
</div>
```

Part of this elements hidden by `.wrapper` with `overflow:hidden`. I use Colorbox for show fullsize pictures. My problem is that, when I reach to hidden elements in Colorbox window and closed him, earlier hidden elements scrolled into view of `.wrapper`, but I need that all elements stay as them was at start.

See https://jsfiddle.net/g26zxz9u/

Click on first element, click twice "Next" button and click "Close" at the end. First and second elements will be hidden, third and fourth will be shown. But I need that first and second elemet be visible always.

Answer (score 0):

You need add `returnFocus: false` property in colorbox init:

```
$('.container').colorbox({
  rel: 'group',
  returnFocus: false
});
```